# How to mux raw PCM with h.264 to MP4 with ffmpeg API?

Tags: c, ffmpeg, h.264, pcm

I'm doing some stuff with real-time multimedia transporting with FFmpeg API. Due to the requests of transporting audio/video data separately, so I need to mix them into an mp4 file at the receiver side.

Now I can mux PCM and H.264 into mp4 file, but when playing, only images come out, the audio can't.
PCM raw data attribute: 8000 sample rate, mono channel, 16 bit.

Can anybody give some advice to me? Thanks a lot.

I've tried to add WAV header to in_pcm_file, and make sure the pcm file can be played by Windows Media Player. But still not working in MP4 file.

```
int muxerData(char *in_h264_file,
              char *in_pcm_file,
              char *out_mp4_file,
              char *angle)
{
    AVFormatContext *ifmt_ctx_v = NULL;
    AVFormatContext *ifmt_ctx_a = NULL;
    AVFormatContext *ofmt_ctx = NULL;
    AVFormatContext *ifmt_ctx = NULL;

    AVOutputFormat *ofmt = NULL;

    AVPacket pkt = {0};
    AVCodec *dec = NULL;

    AVStream *in_stream = NULL;
    AVStream *out_stream = NULL;

    int ret = 0;
    unsigned int i = 0;
    int videoindex_v = -1;
    int videoindex_out = -1;
    int audioindex_a = -1;
    int audioindex_out = -1;
    int frame_index = 0;
    int64_t cur_pts_v = 0;
    int64_t cur_pts_a = 0;

    int stream_index = 0;

    int compare_tag = -1;

    char log_buf[1024] = {0};

    avcodec_register_all();
    av_register_all();

    //Input
    if ((ret = avformat_open_input(&ifmt_ctx_a, in_pcm_file, NULL, NULL)) < 0)
    {
        av_strerror(ret, log_buf, 1024);
        printf("Couldn't open file %s: %d(%s)", in_pcm_file, ret, log_buf);
        goto end;
    }

    if ((ret = avformat_find_stream_info(ifmt_ctx_a, 0)) < 0)
    {
        printf("Failed to retrieve input stream information");
        //if (acc_length>0)
        //  goto end;
    }

    if ((ret = avformat_open_input(&ifmt_ctx_v, in_h264_file, NULL, NULL)) < 0)
    {
        printf("Could not open input file:%d\n", ret);
        goto end;
    }

    if ((ret = avformat_find_stream_info(ifmt_ctx_v, 0)) < 0)
    {
        printf("Failed to retrieve input stream information");
        goto end;
    }

    av_dump_format(ifmt_ctx_v, 0, in_h264_file, 0);
    av_dump_format(ifmt_ctx_a, 0, in_pcm_file, 0);

    //Output
    avformat_alloc_output_context2(&ofmt_ctx, NULL, NULL, out_mp4_file);
    if (!ofmt_ctx)
    {
        printf("Could not create output context\n");
        ret = AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
        goto end;
    }

    ofmt = ofmt_ctx->oformat;

    for (i = 0; i < ifmt_ctx_v->nb_streams; i++)
    {
        //Create output AVStream according to input AVStream
        if (ifmt_ctx_v->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
        {
            in_stream = ifmt_ctx_v->streams[i];
            out_stream = avformat_new_stream(ofmt_ctx, in_stream->codec->codec);
            videoindex_v = i;

            if (!out_stream)
            {
                printf("Failed allocating output stream\n");
                ret = AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
                goto end;
            }

            videoindex_out = out_stream->index;

            //Copy the settings of AVCodecContext
            ret = av_dict_set(&out_stream->metadata, "rotate", angle, 0);

            if (avcodec_copy_context(out_stream->codec, in_stream->codec) < 0)
            {
                printf("Failed to copy context from input to output stream codec context\n");
                goto end;
            }

            out_stream->codec->codec_tag = 0;
            if (ofmt_ctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
            {
                out_stream->codec->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
            }

            break;
        }
    }


    for (i = 0; i < ifmt_ctx_a->nb_streams; i++)
    {
        printf("===========acc=====from======:%d\n", ifmt_ctx_a->nb_streams);

        //Create output AVStream according to input AVStream
        if (ifmt_ctx_a->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO)
        {
            in_stream = ifmt_ctx_a->streams[i];
            out_stream = avformat_new_stream(ofmt_ctx, in_stream->codec->codec);
            audioindex_a = i;

            if (!out_stream)
            {
                printf("Failed allocating output stream\n");
                ret = AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
                goto end;
            }

            audioindex_out = out_stream->index;

            //Copy the settings of AVCodecContext
            if (avcodec_copy_context(out_stream->codec, in_stream->codec) < 0)
            {
                printf("Failed to copy context from input to output stream codec context\n");
                goto end;
            }

            if (ofmt_ctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
            {
                out_stream->codec->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
            }

            break;
        }
    }


    printf("==========Output Information==========\n");
    av_dump_format(ofmt_ctx, 0, out_mp4_file, 1);
    printf("======================================\n");

    //Open output file
    if (!(ofmt->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE))
    {
        if (avio_open(&ofmt_ctx->pb, out_mp4_file, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE) < 0)
        {
            printf("Could not open output file '%s'", out_mp4_file);
            goto end;
        }
    }

    //Write file header
    int header_ret = avformat_write_header(ofmt_ctx, NULL);
    if (header_ret < 0)
    {
        av_strerror(header_ret, log_buf, 1024);
        printf("Error occurred when opening output file:%d (%s)\n", header_ret, log_buf);
        goto end;
    }

    //FIX
    //AVBitStreamFilterContext* h264bsfc = av_bitstream_filter_init("h264_mp4toannexb");
    //AVBitStreamFilterContext* aacbsfc = av_bitstream_filter_init("aac_adtstoasc");


    while (1)
    {
        //Get an AVPacket
        //if (acc_length>0)
        //{
        compare_tag = av_compare_ts(cur_pts_v,
                                    ifmt_ctx_v->streams[videoindex_v]->time_base,
                                    cur_pts_a,
                                    ifmt_ctx_a->streams[audioindex_a]->time_base);
        //}

        if (compare_tag <= 0)
        {
            ifmt_ctx = ifmt_ctx_v;
            stream_index = videoindex_out;

            if (av_read_frame(ifmt_ctx, &pkt) >= 0)
            {
                do
                {
                    in_stream = ifmt_ctx->streams[pkt.stream_index];
                    out_stream = ofmt_ctx->streams[stream_index];

                    if (pkt.stream_index == videoindex_v)
                    {
                        //FIX No PTS (Example: Raw H.264)
                        //Simple Write PTS
                        if (pkt.pts == AV_NOPTS_VALUE)
                        {
                            //Write PTS
                            AVRational time_base1 = in_stream->time_base;
                            //Duration between 2 frames (us)
                            int64_t calc_duration = (double)AV_TIME_BASE / av_q2d(in_stream->r_frame_rate);
                            //Parameters
                            pkt.pts = (double)(frame_index*calc_duration) / (double)(av_q2d(time_base1)*AV_TIME_BASE);
                            pkt.dts = pkt.pts;
                            pkt.duration = (double)calc_duration / (double)(av_q2d(time_base1)*AV_TIME_BASE);
                            frame_index++;
                        }

                        cur_pts_v = pkt.pts;
                        break;
                    }
                } while (av_read_frame(ifmt_ctx, &pkt) >= 0);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ifmt_ctx = ifmt_ctx_a;
            stream_index = audioindex_out;
            if (av_read_frame(ifmt_ctx, &pkt) >= 0)
            {
                do
                {
                    in_stream = ifmt_ctx->streams[pkt.stream_index];
                    out_stream = ofmt_ctx->streams[stream_index];

                    if (pkt.stream_index == audioindex_a)
                    {
                        //FIX No PTS
                        //Simple Write PTS
                        if (pkt.pts == AV_NOPTS_VALUE)
                        {
                            //Write PTS
                            AVRational time_base1 = in_stream->time_base;
                            //Duration between 2 frames (us)
                            int64_t calc_duration = (double)AV_TIME_BASE / av_q2d(in_stream->r_frame_rate);
                            //Parameters
                            pkt.pts = (double)(frame_index*calc_duration) / (double)(av_q2d(time_base1)*AV_TIME_BASE);
                            pkt.dts = pkt.pts;
                            pkt.duration = (double)calc_duration / (double)(av_q2d(time_base1)*AV_TIME_BASE);
                            frame_index++;
                        }
                        cur_pts_a = pkt.pts;

                        break;
                    }
                } while (av_read_frame(ifmt_ctx, &pkt) >= 0);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        //FIX:Bitstream Filter
        //av_bitstream_filter_filter(h264bsfc, in_stream->codec, NULL, &pkt.data, &pkt.size, pkt.data, pkt.size, 0);
        //av_bitstream_filter_filter(aacbsfc, out_stream->codec, NULL, &pkt.data, &pkt.size, pkt.data, pkt.size, 0);

        //Convert PTS/DTS
        pkt.pts = av_rescale_q_rnd(pkt.pts,
                                   in_stream->time_base,
                                   out_stream->time_base,
                                   (AVRounding)(AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF | AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX));

        pkt.dts = av_rescale_q_rnd(pkt.dts,
                                   in_stream->time_base,
                                   out_stream->time_base,
                                   (AVRounding)(AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF | AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX));

        pkt.duration = av_rescale_q(pkt.duration, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base);
        pkt.pos = -1;
        pkt.stream_index = stream_index;

        printf("Write 1 Packet. size:%5d\tpts:%lld\n", pkt.size, pkt.pts);

        if (av_interleaved_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, &pkt) < 0)
        {
            printf("Error muxing packet\n");
            break;
        }

        av_free_packet(&pkt);
    }

    //Write file trailer
    av_write_trailer(ofmt_ctx);

    //av_bitstream_filter_close(h264bsfc);
    //av_bitstream_filter_close(aacbsfc);


end:

    avformat_close_input(&ifmt_ctx_v);
    avformat_close_input(&ifmt_ctx_a);

    /* close output */
    if (ofmt_ctx && !(ofmt->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE))
    {
        avio_close(ofmt_ctx->pb);
    }

    avformat_free_context(ofmt_ctx);

    if ((ret < 0) && (ret != AVERROR_EOF))
    {
        printf("Error occurred.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("======muxer mp4 success =====!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While you are new to SO, it is worth learning how to ask questions, so that you will get people to help you. There is a skill to asking questions, and it takes time to put one together properly. You may in fact solve the problem while you are preparing the question, as it will force you to narrow down the scope of the problem as you go - this is an essential skill that forms part of a good developers workflow. The problem is usually simple when you find it, the investigation can often take much longer than the fix. stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mp4 does not have official support for PCM. Even if some tools can create a non standard mp4 with pcm, the player won’t know how to read it.

Comment: I've tried to encode PCM to AAC and mux with H.264 into MP4, it works, thanks a lot